# does polarization of light beam increase transmittance through metals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I don't know if this is a possibility.polarization makes's light transmit fully at brewster's angle,so for other angles only some part should be reflected and transmittance should be high.Is there any other way to increase transmittance through metals?.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1l7ddl/what_does_the_index_of_refraction_mean_for_metals/

Answer (score 0):

Light is not transmitted through metals because they are conductors. Light is an electrical and magnetic oscillation, and an electrical force inside a conductor causes a current to flow, dissipating the force. Only non-conducting materials can be transparent to visible light. For example, even the thinnest possible gold leaf is not at all translucent.

Comment: When light is incidenting on a metal surface,the free electrons in the metal oscillate due to the the oscillation of electric field of light.If the electron is oscillating,the resultant em wave can propagate in two direction either right or left perpendicular to the direction of oscillation,If we take left side as reflection and right side as transmittance.Why one side is favoured?.I want to know why it reflects,while it can refract to0.These reflections are due to free electrons thats why conductors interact and non-conductors don't.Why this specific directional property?.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Why reflection is favoured over refraction,if both are possible?